# how to insert multiple values into a table cell in sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `listbox` item in my website with `selectionmode` as "multilple". I want to insert all the selected items to a column in the table in my `sql` server when I click the submit button.

This is my `listbox` items.

```
<asp:TableCell>
    <asp:ListBox ID="lbLanguagesKnown" runat="server" Height="217px" 
        SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="-1">-Select Languages-</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Arabic</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Bengali</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">English</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">German</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="5">Hindi</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="6">Japanese</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="7">Javanese</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="8">Mandarin</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="9">Others</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="10">Portuguese</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="11">Russian</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="12">Spanish</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>
</asp:TableCell>
```

How is that possible? Please help.

Comment: FYI, Tables have *columns*, not *cells*.  Cells are found in spreadsheets and prisons.

Comment: sorry. I corrected it.

Comment: Actually i have many other controls like textboxes,calendar controls,fileupload and so on. I have a submit button. On click of that i want to insert all these values to the user table. Since the listbox items are many in number, i am stuck up other.

Comment: Should i create another table and link these two tables using foreign key relations. Is that the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining all the values and putting them into single column is NOT A GOOD IDEA AT ALL... As above answer it does not even meet the 1NF condition for data normalization, result of it would be inefficient disk space usage, slow queries (really messy to get results out from such a table from my understanding). But if you still want to do it you can probably try concatenating the values with a delimeter (, or /) and insert them  so that it can be split out if required at a later stage..

Answer (score 5):

You likely don't want to do this, as you'll be breaking even first normal form. Instead, it may make more sense to model the relationship as a many-to-many.

In this case you would have a `Languages` table, an (e.g.) `User` table, and then a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) (e.g. `LanguagesKnown`) which links many languages to many users using two foreign keys for each row in the junction table.

Comment: +1, but I don't think the OP is close to being able to design a database at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple loop:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Language VALUES(@languageID, @languageName);";
using (var con = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    con.Open();
    foreach (ListItem item in lbLanguagesKnown.Items)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@languageID", int.Parse(item.Value));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@languageName", item.Text);
            int insertedCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

I have used sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection. The `using`-statement is used to ensure that the connection gets closed as soon as possible (even in case of an exception).

However, the requirement makes little sense. Why do you want to insert masterdata when the user selects part of it. Sounds as if you actually want to insert in a different table which links to the language table.

For example:

Table1: `UserLanguages` with `UserID` + `LanguageID`

Table2: `Languages` with above model

Comment: I want to insert only the user selected values to the table. Also there are many other controls also like textboxes which accept username,password,DOB, file upload and download controls. I have a submit button in the page. When i click on that, i want to insert all these values to the user table.